# Npm build error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/intro' in

Tags: module, npm-install, build-error, npm-build

When I try running npm build, I get this error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './component/intro' in 'C:\Users\rogal\Winter2024\CS312\Py labs\test\react-attempt\react-attempt\src'"

One of my components was originally named Intro, and this issue occured after I renamed it to "Fader". I have checked my package.json and package.lock.json, there is no "intro" anywhere in either package.
I have tried deleting my build folder, and my node-modules, and then rebuilding or npm installing. I run those in the same folder as the package.json, which is react-attempt/react-attempt. Every time I get this same error though.
Here is my basic directory. Any ideas?
[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkD8D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look on your Imports, that error means you’re trying to import a non existing file